# UIImagePickerController landscape wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem with `UIImagePickerController` on my `iPad`. it is presented as a `modalView` (`presentViewController`:).

All orientations are allowed and should work.

If I push a `ViewController` in Portrait mode on this VC (this is the main view of the App), go back to the Springboard, rotate the iPad to `Landscape` mode, reopen my App, There is a big `black space` on the screen.
However, the camera controls are well shown.

Has anyone already seen this kind of bug?

Thank you.

This is better with a screenshot[image: ipad screenshot]

Comment: I had this same problem on a recent project. It ended up taking too much time so I just subclassed UIImagePickerController to return the preferred initial orientation. It's ugly but it got me close enough to move on. I would love to see a real solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do methods do you add to this subclass?

Comment: - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

This forces it to launch in portrait then the user can rotate it back to landscape if they want... Like I said it's ugly .

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem. No solution yet...

Comment: OK. The solution I found for now is to use the AVCamCaptureManager directly, so the "camera" layer can be reframed. I also encountered a problem with the UIImagePickerController showing a blackscreen with iOS7. The AVCam solution corrects it. Thanks for your help!!